# Can we use pthread library for opencv C++ programming?

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading, opencv

I have implemented a openCV program which can capture frames from video file and process it and create a new file. That is doing for single in file . Now I want for multiple files . then I have an idea about POSIX thread pthread library . Is that is a good or bad idea . Actually when I implement pthreads in opencv program I got some errors like following :

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (_src.sameSize(_dst) && dcn == scn) in
>   accumulate, file
>   /home/satinder/opencv_installation/OpenCV/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/accum.cpp,
>   line 915
>
> what(): 
>   /home/satinder/opencv_installation/OpenCV/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/accum.cpp:915:
>   error: (-215) _src.sameSize(_dst) && dcn == scn in function accumulate
>       Aborted (core dumped)
>
> corrupted double-linked list: 0x00007fcd048f73d0 ***
>       Aborted (core dumped)

**seg fault** also some time .

Is there any possible way how I can implement multi-threading or equivalent my goal make a program which can get more that one input files for same processing.

FOllowing is my code snapshot :

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


void * VideoCap(void *);


void * VideoCap(void *arg)
{
         VideoCapture cap((char *)arg); // open the video file for reading

    if ( !cap.isOpened() )  // if not success, exit program
    {
         cout << "Cannot open the video file" << endl;
         exit(1);
    }

    //cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, 300); //start the video at 300ms

    double fps = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS); //get the frames per seconds of the video

     cout << "Frame per seconds : " << fps << endl;

    namedWindow("MyVideo",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window called "MyVideo"

    while(1)
    {
        Mat frame;

        bool bSuccess = cap.read(frame); // read a new frame from video

         if (!bSuccess) //if not success, break loop
        {
                        cout << "Cannot read the frame from video file" << endl;
                       break;
        }

        imshow("MyVideo", frame); //show the frame in "MyVideo" window

        if(waitKey(30) == 27) //wait for 'esc' key press for 30 ms. If 'esc' key is pressed, break loop
       {
                cout << "esc key is pressed by user" << endl;
                break;
       }
    }

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

        int ret ;
        pthread_t th[2];

        ret = pthread_create(&th[0] , NULL , VideoCap , (void *)"cctv3.mp4");
        if(0 == ret)
        {
                cout << "Thread 1 is created successfull" << endl;
        }
        ret = pthread_create(&th[1] , NULL , VideoCap , (void *)"cctv10.mp4");
        if(0 == ret)
        {
                cout << "Thread 2 is created successfull" << endl;
        }
        pthread_join(th[0] , NULL);
        pthread_join(th[1] , NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you include [mcve] it may be possible to help you.

Comment: It's very likely that your threads are working but you are trying to access the same data from different threads and that is why you are getting errors. Without a code example, that shows where you think the error is, it's quite hard to tell.

Comment: @GPPK yes I think you are right . I will post my code but that is very large file.

Comment: Post the *relevant* part of your code not all of it!

Comment: @GPPK I post some part please see.

Comment: @J.J.Hakala  please see my code snapshot

Comment: I am no expert on this, but it seems odd to run two threads that *compete* with each other to capture the next frame. I would be more inclined to have one thread capturing frames as fast as it can into a ring of, say, 2-8 buffers and have another thread processing the frames from the ring of buffers and have some semaphores/mutexes protecting the buffers.

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with your code

```
namedWindow("MyVideo",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window called "MyVideo"
```

You are creating two threads, so the windows should have different identifiers.

```
namedWindow((char *)arg, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
...
imshow((char *)arg, frame);
```

Since this question was posted with *linux* tag, I'm guessing that gtk is relevant. After inserting the directives

```
#include <gdk/gdk.h>
#include <gtk/gtkmain.h>
```

at the beginning of the file and then in the `main()`

```
pthread_t th[2];

gtk_disable_setlocale();
gtk_init(&argc, &argv); 
gdk_threads_init();
```

New linker / compiler flags are probably needed,

```
g++ -O -Wall test.cpp -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_core `pkg-config --libs --cflags gdk-2.0 gtk+-2.0`
```

After these changes there was still an occasional crash, so I added `gdk_threads_enter()` and `gdk_threads_leave();` calls to test if they would help:

```
gdk_threads_enter();
namedWindow ((char *) arg, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
gdk_threads_leave();
```

Since the crashing was not reproducible, it is hard to tell if those lines have any effect.